# The integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-z^2x^2}/x^n\,dx$ for complex $z$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am looking for a solution of the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-z^2x^2}}{x^n}\,dx$$
for complex $z$ and positive integers $n$. Wolfram Alpha gives the result, for example for $=2$ as
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-z^2x^2}}{x^2}\,dx=-2\sqrt{\pi}\left|z\right|$$
but it is unclear to me if this holds for complex $z$. For example, for $z=i$, the integral should diverge. Does anyone have a reference for this integral or a solution?

Comment: It always diverges ($x=0$ is a non-integrable singularity).

Comment: @metamorphy But does this also hold for complex $z$?

Comment: @HerpDerpington It converges if you define it with a [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) which makes:$$\text{PV} \int_{-a}^a \frac{dx}{x}=0$$ for most a.

Comment: @TymaGaidash: What if $n$ is even? As an example, for $n=2$ and $z=0$ you have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2}$ and that diverges, even as a Cauchy principal value.

Comment: @MartinR Then “Intuitively” the [-a,0] area “cancels” the [0,a] area because the two are the same for odd degree, but for even degree, then it “graphically” diverges as there is no area under the $x$-axis. If you really want a way to find such a values, then the closest thing coming to mind is [Ramanujan Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation), which is like integration, but not exactly. Maybe use a series “representation” of the integral and use the link?